# Is it possible to remove the cursor from this dynamic query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Simplified example of what I have:

Two tables (table_1 and table_2) which have one similar column (Id) but also several "payload" columns with different names (col_1_1, col_2_1, col_2_2). Amount of "payload" columns is different for different tables.

I am interested in extracting the IDs from both tables into another table for rows which have all "payload" columns empty.

There is a list of all "payload" columns for all tables which can be used (#temp)

This is how it is done with cursor:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (tab nvarchar(20) not null, col nvarchar(20) not null)
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'table_1','col_1_1' UNION SELECT 'table_2','col_2_1' UNION SELECT 'table_2','col_2_2'

DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR (SELECT DISTINCT tab FROM #temp)
OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @table_name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = ISNULL(@sql,'')+col+' IS NULL AND ' FROM #temp WHERE tab = @table_name
    SET @sql += 'Id IS NOT NULL'
    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #temp_master SELECT ID FROM '+@table_name+' WHERE '+@sql
    print @sql
    SET @sql = ''
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @table_name
END
CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

This is the result:

```
INSERT INTO #temp_master SELECT ID FROM table_1 WHERE col_1_1 IS NULL AND Id IS NOT NULL
INSERT INTO #temp_master SELECT ID FROM table_2 WHERE col_2_1 IS NULL AND col_2_2 IS NULL AND Id IS NOT NULL
```

Is it possible to remove the cursor to get the same resulting dynamic query? The problem is that I am unable to have dynamic "IS NULL AND" part for different tables when I remove the cursor.

Comment: if you want to change object names(tables/databases/schemas/...) you will have to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to get rid of that cursor. This is probably what you need:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (tab nvarchar(20) not null, col nvarchar(20) not null)
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'table_1','col_1_1' UNION SELECT 'table_2','col_2_1' UNION SELECT 'table_2','col_2_2'

DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

select @sql = 'INSERT INTO #temp_master SELECT ID FROM ' + t.tab + ' WHERE Id IS NOT NULL AND ' + substring(t.cols, 0, len(t.cols)-3) + '
' + @sql from
(
SELECT
distinct
    t2.tab,
    stuff(
    (
    select t1.col + cast(' IS NULL AND ' as varchar(max))
    from #temp t1
    WHERE t1.tab = t2.tab
    order by t1.tab
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 0, '') AS cols
FROM
    #temp t2
    ) as t
order by t.tab desc

print @sql 

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a regular `CONCAT` question, you can find many approaches to accomplish it without cursor. One of approaches is a cursor by the way and it's not that bad for such a task.

Another and more popular - `FOR XML` which can guarantee row order if any defined:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #temp (tab nvarchar(20) not null, col nvarchar(20) not null)
INSERT INTO #temp SELECT 'table_1','col_1_1' UNION SELECT 'table_2','col_2_1' UNION SELECT 'table_2','col_2_2'

SET @sql = (SELECT (  
SELECT '
INSERT INTO #temp_master (ID) SELECT t.ID FROM '+t.tab +' t WHERE t.Id IS NOT NULL'
    + (select ' AND t.' + tt.col + ' is NULL' from #temp tt WHERE tt.tab = t.tab FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
FROM #temp t
GROUP BY t.tab
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'))

PRINT @sql

DROP TABLE #temp
```

A little "tricky" thing is that you have two things to collaps:

- many queries (separate for specific table)
- many columns per table

So you there is one inner `FOR XML` to collapse columns per table and another - to combine all queries into one big script.